# pg_upgrade fails with an unspecified error

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I’m running Postgres 9.1’s pg_ugrade to migrate from 9.0 to 9.1 on Windows x64. After editing the permissions to allow full trust, running the tool as the postgres user, and working around a bug whereby pg_upgrade leaves the "old" store locked and refusing to run again ("there seems to be a postmaster servicing old cluster"), it now fails without explaining what’s wrong:

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking current, bin, and data directories                 ok
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is a superuser                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* system oid user data types                ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Creating catalog dump                                       ok

There were problems executing ""C:\Progs\Postgres\9.0\bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "nul" -D "C:\Progs\Postgres\9.0-data"  stop >> "nul" 2>&1"

Failure, exiting
```

Is this tool production-ready or am I wasting my time? If this is what I should be doing, what are your suggestions for solving the current failure?

Comment: For future users finding this topic because of the "servicing old cluster" message: if you truly do not have a postmaster running, and you are certain that you shut down the postmaster cleanly, this message means that there is a `postmaster.id` file in your directory that you need to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Basically pg_upgrade *is* production ready.

Unfortunately the early builds of 9.1 had some bugs related to pg_upgrade and Windows. These were fixed in 9.1.3 as far as I know.

Comment: Will check it out next time I do an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor version and, as such, you shouldn't need to run `pg_upgrade`. My understanding is that `pg_upgrade` is only for major version upgrades (e.g. 8.4 -> 9.0)

**Edit:**

I stand corrected.

- Do your Windows Event logs give any more detail about what's going on?
- Have you tried the alternate path described in the link you provided (17.6.1. Upgrading Data via pg_dump)?

**Edit 2:**

I've honestly never used pg_upgrade and have only ever gone about it using pg_dump. Are you using the `-l` switch and dumping the session to a log?

Also, based on the error, it looks like postgres is having a hard time starting. Have you tried manually starting the server?

Comment: Negative; Postgres considers 9.0 -> 9.1 to be a major version change ([reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html), second paragraph).

Comment: fascinating. I stand corrected.

Comment: I did end up upgrading via pg_dump, but I hate doing that. So I’d like to find out how to do this via pg_upgrade next time. I was not using `-l`. Manually starting the server works fine (both the old and the new version).

Comment: Ok. Glad it worked out for you. `-l` will allow you to dump the session to a log. Perhaps then you could get a better explanation of what the problem was.